# go, how to invoke a func if i declare it with type only receiver?

Tags: go

Just be curious, how to invoke the below go func `func (t) test()` if i declare it with type only receiver, is it even valid? like: https://play.golang.org/p/k8QukaCZdUN

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type t int

func (t) test() {
    fmt.Println(233)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(666666)
}
```

I tried to build and run it, seems ok... but:

1. What exactly is this `func (t) test()` and how to invoke it?
2. Is there any meaningful use case for this kind of declaration (i mean bare type as receiver)?

**More context:**

I was triggered to think about this bcoz i want to find an idiomatic/elegant way to expose all values of an enum(iota) to external packages, currently i am doing something like: https://play.golang.org/p/iD0Aq_Mn2sj

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Gender int

const (
    Male Gender = iota + 1
    Female
)

func (g Gender) All() [2]string {
    return [...]string{"MALE", "FEMALE"}
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("All gender types:", Gender(0).All())
}
```

It works, so any `Gender` instance can invoke its `All` function to get all the `Gender` types, but it feels a bit weird, so i start thinking of **whether it is possible to register a func on the type only, not the instances, so i can do: `package.Gender.All()`**, is it possible in go?

btw, no global var.

Answer (score 2):

> is it even valid?

As shown by your example, yes.

> What exactly is this func (t) test() and how to invoke it?

It's a normal method.  You invoke it like a normal method.  See:

```golang
var val t
val.test()
```

> Is there any meaningful use case for this kind of declaration (i mean bare type as receiver)?

The main difference with this form of method is that you can't access the receiver (as it's unnamed).  So it's effectively similar to a ["static" method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_(computer_programming)#Static_methods) (although it's really not. you still need an instance to call it)

---

If you want to get all values of an enum, there's no reason to make it a type method.  All it does is create an extra step to call it:

```golang
var g Gender // create a useless variable so we can call the method
g.All() // actually call the method
```

You might as well make a regular function for it.

Comment: seems an exported regular func is the best for this scenario